# Data type range values using any SQL query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle

I was referring to [Java Constant Field Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html) and thought if boundary values ( say `MIN_VALUE`, `MAX_VALUE` in case of Numeric data types ) can be retrieved for data types using an SQL query.

For example

```
select  
    int.signed_min_value as int_sgnd_min,  
    int.unsigned_min_value as int_usgnd_min,  
    int.signed_max_value as int_sgnd_max,  
    int.unsigned_max_value as int_usgnd_max,  
    int.storage_bytes as int_bytes  
from dual;
```

Should be resulting

```
+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
| int_sgnd_min | int_usgnd_min | int_sgnd_max | int_usgnd_max | int_bytes |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
|  -2147483648 |             0 |   2147483647 |    4294967295 |       4   |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
```

Above results are [storage and range values defined for MySQL integer data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html).
Other data type storage requirements in MySQL are as defined [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html).

I gave a sample on numeric data type only but I am also expecting a possibility for other data types.

I do am aware that we can only `select` columns and expressions, but trying to understand if there is such a facility in SQL like in Java and other programming languages.

Comment: @Diego Well, no constraint. Generic is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean Sql Server, you can get that info from the sys.types table. If you do:

```
select * from sys.types
where name='int'
```

you can check the max_length, which indicates the Maximum length (in bytes) of the type. So int = 4 bites whihc gives you -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)

Comment: In SQL Server, how do I get range values if `name='date'`? AFAIK, Oracle date ranges from `January 1, 4712 BC` to `December 31, 9999 AD`